# Python PDF Merging - How to keep original file name and working in bulk

Tags: python, pdf

Thanks for the help in advance. I have been searching for a solution but it seems that what I'm looking for is always just a bit different than any posts I've found.

**I need to add a single title page(a pdf) to thousands of local pdfs. I have a directory of thousands of pdfs that all need to have a single title page added to them. The title page is going to be the same every iteration, but the catch is I need to keep the file name of the original pdf that I'm adding the title page to.**

I was thinking it would be simple enough to loop through my directory, save the current file name, merge a pdf to the front of it, output as the filename that was saved as the variable in a different directory.

I was able to come up with a script that will merge all the  files in the current directory but I've hit a wall with progress. Here is the code so far.

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger
import glob
import os

pdf_files = glob.glob("./*.pdf")

output_pdf = "PDF-Output.pdf"

merger = PdfFileMerger()

for pdf in pdf_files:
    merger.append(open(pdf, 'rb'))

with open(output_pdf, 'wb') as fout:
    merger.write(fout)

print("PDF Merge success.")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the title page stored in `title.pdf`.
You then have to merge the title page and each pdf.

```py
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger, PdfFileReader
import glob
import os

title_file = "./title.pdf"
pdf_files = glob.glob("./*.pdf")

for name in pdf_files:
    if name is not title_file:
        merger = PdfFileMerger()
        merger.append(PdfFileReader(title_file, 'rb')
        merger.append(PdfFileReader(name, 'rb')
        merger.write(name)
        merger.close()
```

This loops over all files in `pdf_files` and prepends the title page to it. It then saves the file to its old name, overwriting the old file.

I highly recommend making a backup before running this.

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately I am getting an error on line 12 here.

`merger.append(PdfFileReader(name, 'rb')
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: I didn't realize that there were 2 parentheses missing - works like a charm! Thanks so much!